# ORACLE SQL check if the row number of the table is n, then perform a join

Tags: sql, oracle

TABLE student: ID, ID2, NAME, AGE

TABLE class: ID, CLASS_NAME, some other columns

TABLE school: ID2, some other columns.

I am trying to perform below in Oracle SQL:

If the count of the records in TABLE "student" with age>5, is 1,
join the student table with "CLASS" table by "ID", else, join the student table with "school" table by "ID2".

I found I cannot put count in where clause. Can someone help?

Comment: That's a strange task. What is your result supposed to look like? You do know that the query must select the same number and types of columns in both cases, don't you? You can do something like `select coalesce(class.class_name, school.school_name) as class_or_school_name`, but is this really what you want? Please edit your request and show a sample result for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions:

```
select s.*, . . .
from (select s.*, sum(case when age > 5 then 1 else 0 end) over () as cnt5
      from students s
     ) s left join
     class c
     on c.id = s.id and cnt5 = 1 left join
     school sch
     on sch.id2 = s.id2 and cnt5 <> 1
where c.id is not null or sch.id is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use left join with case

```
   select s.*, case when age > 5 then COALESCE (c.ID,scl.ID2) as id 
     from student s
    left join class c on s.ID=c.ID
    left join school scl on s.ID2=scl.ID2
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon said window functions are an option, but this is also a rare occasion where you can deliberately perform a cross join:

```
select s.*
,...
from students s
left join
(
select count(*) as RECORD_COUNT
from students
where age > 5
) sub
on 1 = 1
left join class c
on s.id = c.id
and sub.record_count = 1
left join school h
on s.id2 = h.id2
and c.id is null
```